# Coolant boils over but temp gauge registers normal

Tags: ford, overheating

I have a 2002 Ford Taurus 3.0 L V6. I have had trouble off and on with it running hot for about a year.

At first I put a new thermostat on it and it seemed to fix the problem.  Month or so later, it started doing it again.  Thought I might have gotten a bad one or not gotten it on exactly right.  Got another one.  Didn't help.

Fan didn't seem to be working right - replaced the relays, which helped the fan but it still ran hot.  Particularly going uphill.  I'd come home and the trip up the driveway would have it registered hot and steam and water coming out from under the cap.

Flushed the system and put in new water pump.  Fixed it for a while.

Started losing water from the pipe running behind the engine where it splits and one goes under the dash and one around under the engine. Used quik steel and pretty much got that fixed.

Fan quit working - rigged it so that I can turn it on and off with a switch in the car.  Now, instead of leaking a little, it's spewing from under the cap.

After about 30 minutes driving, with the fan on and the gauge registering normal, the water begins spewing from under the cap.  It doesn't register as hot until too much water has spewed out.

I got a new cap - didn't help.

Check engine light came on.  Went to auto parts store, they checked it and said it was misfiring on one cylinder.

There is no water in the oil or oil in the water.  From what I've read of misfires, that shouldn't be forcing the water out from under the cap.  If I could blow it up, I would but I need to be able to drive it until I can afford something else.

The radiator is enclosed so I can't get to it to check it out.  Any and all suggestions welcome (except using a flamethrower instead of a grenade - I already thought of that.)

Comment: When you flushed cooling system did you fill it with 50/50 coolant/distilled water? or just water?

Comment: Is the misfire persistent or was it a one-off?

Answer (score 2):

The cylinder head gasket could have blown between a cylinder and the water jacket.  Use a compression tester to check the compression on each cylinder.  If the gasket has blown, you will have low compression on at least one cylinder.  You would only get a mix of oil and water if the gasket had blown between the oil and water ways.